# Is it possible to speed time in a computer?

Tags: time

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask this question, if it isn't please redirect me.

Anyways, the question is whether it is possible to speed the time passing in a computer.

For example, a program would run an audio every second, so it requests something like this

`if ( getmillis()%1000 == 0 ): playAudio()`

So can I speed up this time such that a milli second for me is 2 milli second for the computer? Can this be done inside a program? or would I have to change the computer's crystal oscillator? would that even work?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to teach my neural network to play a game but the game runs slow, I thought maybe speeding time would speed the game, thus increasing the speed of the learning process(which is limited by the game speed).

Comment: I think the easiest way to do that is to run your game in an emulator or virtual machine, see e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/619848/can-i-speed-up-a-vm-to-emulate-the-passage-of-time or https://askubuntu.com/questions/575727/guest-ubuntu-vm-speed-up-clock

Comment: Is it a game that you can code yourself (so as to avoid the dependence on real time passing)? Is it a game that allows saving replays, or does it have some binary/textual way of representing the game state? I would look into how games are saved - if such functionality even exists.

Comment: @mb21 yes that is a very interesting solution!!

Comment: @Dev-iL the game is the dinosaur mini game from google chrome

Comment: if it's a JavaScript game you're even more in luck: https://betterexplained.com/articles/speed-up-your-javascript-load-time/